# How to extrude an irregular shape evenly and uniformly?

Tags: extrude

looking for the best way to extrude evenly. Im trying to make a "lip" for the carapace pictured and its not extruding evenly. I have tried using the normals/solidifying etc. Im not sure there is an easy way. Even when I do it seperatly (front half circle first then the top bit) it still does not extrude evenly. If you look at the red circle you will see the difference.

I am trying to create a uniform extruded lip/flange and the thickness is not uniform:

[image: armour to extrude evenly to create lip]

Any tips much appreciated

Comment: what did you use? Did you use **Alt+E** > **Extrude faces along normals**  with **Even** enabled?

Comment: **I** inset all faces  (you may need to check 'Boundary', and 'Even',)  followed by **Alt E** > Extrude faces along normals, should be even. Is your object non-uniformly scaled? You may need to **Ctrl A** apply the scale.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the *Solidify* modifier there is an option *Even Thickness* which you can enable:

[image: solidify]

If you want to do it with Extrusion in *Edit Mode*, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals* and then press <kbd>S</kbd> to toggle *Even Thickness* ON or OFF, or hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

[image: extrude]